# Dynamic border in excel using vba codes

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a template to generate invoices.  The item details start below cells A6:I6.

I *only* want to add borders to the cells containing data (i.e. if I have 10 items in the invoice then I only want borders added to those 10 items, and not the other item cells.)

However, the rest of the cells (like customer name, amount, etc.) should always have borders.

Comment: Can you provide some code to show what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with VBA for this?  Just use [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enter-and-format-data-fef13169-0a84-4b92-a5ab-d856b0d7c1f7#ID0EAABAAA=Conditional_formatting).  If you [use a Formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) - most likely [`LEN`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/len-lenb-functions-29236f94-cedc-429d-affd-b5e33d2c67cb) or [`ISBLANK`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/is-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665) then this shouldn't be to difficult.

By locking the comparison formula to a specific column (e.g. `=LEN($B1)>0` to check Column B) you can tie the formatting if a section of the row together.

Comment: Great Advice.Never thought of using Conditional formatting,Actually never knew it could be accomplished by using conditional formatting.Got specific result .Thanks a lot.